# Update Workflow with PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have a MOSS 2007 environment which we are upgrading to SharePoint 2013. I have a lot of Designer Workflows in 2007 that usually involve simple activities like sending mail. However some of the mail sending activities have some URL's hard-coded in them. Is there a way to replace all those with new URL's?